# Trying to deploy a mern stack (Node JS) application on heroku (Getting error H10)

Tags: node.js, heroku, deployment

I am just starting with the MERN stack and Node JS to create a simple website - I published the project to github and tried to deploy on Heroku, the deployment is succesfuel; however, when I view the website it tells me

> An error occurred in the application and your page could not be
> served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.
> You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command heroku logs
> --tail

After I checked the Heroku CLI, I got the following error:

> npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2020-10-14T20_29_22_623Z-debug.log
> 2020-10-14T20:29:24.764157+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10
> desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=seer-team-12.herokuapp.com
> request_id=58a4c5ca-5517-423f-a41f-c7d54985c778 fwd="122.58.167.129"
> dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
> 2020-10-14T20:29:25.246802+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10
> desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico"
> host=seer-team-12.herokuapp.com
> request_id=ba173afb-208e-4073-80f0-99f6029545e5 fwd="122.58.167.129"
> dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

I tired many solutions - making sure the PORT is process.env.PORT - and tried to make sure the Procfile is fine.

That is the the github application:
https://github.com/mentalist302/SEER

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Is it working in local ?

Comment: Yes it is working fine in local, continusly crashing in Heroku though

Comment: Are you trying to run the react project or the node project ?

Comment: I am just ttrying to make it work - not really sure, I think locally the react starts. what about Heroku?